# Set up capybara-webkit 1.10.1 on opensuse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, opensuse, capybara-webkit

I got an error when I tried to update capybara-webkit:

```
/usr/lib64/libQtNetwork.so: undefined reference to `SSLv2_client_method'
/usr/lib64/libQtNetwork.so: undefined reference to `SSLv2_server_method'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.webkit_server:414: recipe for target 'webkit_server' failed
make[1]: *** [webkit_server] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/al1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/capybara-webkit-1.10.1/src'
Makefile:39: recipe for target 'sub-src-webkit_server-pro-make_default-ordered' failed
make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-make_default-ordered] Error 2

make failed, exit code 2
```

Please point me to a solution for this problem.
Ruby version 2.2.2.
OS: OpenSuse Leap 42.1.

Comment: What version of Qt is installed?

Comment: Qt version is 5.5.1. But I noted one strange thing: in output of setup capybara-webkit using paths with 'qt4', maybe it's a problem.